# Layout QPushButtons in flexible grid layout using PySide

Tags: python, pyside, qpushbutton

How would I go about having my resizeble dialog auto arrange my pushbuttons to fill as much space as possible like shown here in the image? Do I use a ListView or ListWidget somehow to achieve this?

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice example in the Qt docs that does exactly what you need:

- [QWidgets Flow Layout Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html)

*I know it is not good style to throw a link as an answer, but this is part of the official documentation and I don't see a need to duplicate documentation.*

Comment: Has anyone converted this to pyside for python?

Comment: I found it here on github

Comment: @JokerMartini See https://github.com/pyside/pyside2-setup/blob/5.15/examples/widgets/layouts/flowlayout.py